# Issues in Talend in UBUNTU

Tags: talend

I have downloaded talend 5.3.2 studio in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

When I am opening the TOS_DI-win-x86_64.exe as my system is 64 bit, the studio is not opening. since I am new to ubuntu I am not sure which application should I open with kindly help.

Comment: You can find better answers at http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1):

`TOS_DI-win-x86_64.exe` is the Windows executable. 
The appropriate file for your Ubuntu system is `TOS_DI-linux-gtk-x86_64`